# Unable to make my reactive variables work

Tags: r, shiny

As I am fairly new to R scripting, I am having a hard time to make my app work as it should.

What am I trying to achieve:

1. User uploads a CSV
2. User checks a preview of file (safety check)
3. User executes query
4. Query appears on mainPanel
5. Results are downloadable on csv.

I am able to execute all those points as soon as I upload a file. They happen at the same time, killing the purpose of the application.

**Problem:** I have three outputs which need to be performed at specific actions (Load Preview, Run Query, Download Query Results).

Can someone please help me?

Here is my code:

```
#Libraries to load

library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library('devtools')

#--------------------------------------
# Interface
#--------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Content Upload Report"),

  sidebarPanel(

    h4("1. Select the desired data range and upload your file. A preview will be shown once it gets loaded."),

    # Sidebar with a data range input
    dateRangeInput("dates", "Date range",
                   start = "2017-09-01", end = "2017-09-30", 
                   min = "2017-01-01", max = "2018-12-31",
                   format = "yyyy-mm-dd", startview = "month", weekstart = 1,
                   language = "en", separator = " to "),

    #Sidebar with a file input
    fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
              accept = c(
                "text/csv",
                "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                ".csv")),

    h4("2. Once you see that the list seems correct, click on the button below."),

    tableOutput("preview"),

    #Submit button
    actionButton("startQuery","Start Query",icon ("search"), width = NULL, class="butt"),
    tags$head(tags$style(".butt{background-color:#007fad;} .butt{color: white;}")),

    tags$br(),

    #Warning about loading time
    helpText("When you click the button above, it might take a while until the results are ready.",
             "The size of your list directly impacts the waiting time for the query."),

    #Horizontal Line
    tags$hr(),

    #Download Results
    downloadButton('downloadData1', label = "Download Results", class = "btmcolor"),
    tags$head(tags$style(".btmcolor{background-color:#007fad;} .btmcolor{color: white;}"))

    ),

  mainPanel(

    dataTableOutput("result"),
    tags$style(type="text/css", '#result tfoot {display:none;}')
  )

)

#--------------------------------------
# Server
#--------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output) {

  d<-reactiveValues()

   output$preview <- renderTable({

    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.

    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = FALSE, sep =",")

    #This will be printed on the preview
    head(df)

  })

  output$result <- renderDataTable({

    # Fix data input to format yyyymmdd
    tmp_str <- paste(as.character(input$dates), collapse = " and ")
    tmp_str <- gsub("-", "", tmp_str)

    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.

    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = FALSE, sep =",")

    #Prepare file for query

    #read the user file as a single string into csvString
    csvString <- paste(readLines(inFile$datapath), collapse=", ")
    print(csvString)

    #put all emails into 1 string with quotes around each
    csvString <- paste0(sprintf("%s", csvString), collapse = ", ")

    #Authenticate on DB
    ds <- "authentication string. custom library"

    #Run Query 
    query <- paste0("
                    SELECT item_id, country, total_new_images
                    FROM inventory
                    WHERE item_id IN (", csvString, ")
                    GROUP BY item_id, country
                    ORDER BY item_id
                    ")


    d$data <- ds$execute_query(query) #custom function
    d$result1 <- as.data.frame(d$data)

  })

  #------------------------------------------
  # Download Output
  #------------------------------------------

  output$downloadData1 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
          tmp<- paste(as.character(input$dates), collapse = "_")
          tmp <- gsub("-", "", tmp)
      paste0("content_upload_",tmp,".csv") },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(d$result1, file)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulating your `output` functions inside `observeEvent` would help do that.

```
#Libraries to load

library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library('devtools')

#--------------------------------------
# Interface
#--------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Content Upload Report"),

  sidebarPanel(

    h4("1. Select the desired data range and upload your file. A preview will be shown once it gets loaded."),

    # Sidebar with a data range input
    dateRangeInput("dates", "Date range",
                   start = "2017-09-01", end = "2017-09-30", 
                   min = "2017-01-01", max = "2018-12-31",
                   format = "yyyy-mm-dd", startview = "month", weekstart = 1,
                   language = "en", separator = " to "),

    #Sidebar with a file input
    fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
              accept = c(
                "text/csv",
                "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                ".csv")),

    h4("2. Once you see that the list seems correct, click on the button below."),

    tableOutput("preview"),

    #Submit button
    actionButton("startQuery","Start Query",icon ("search"), width = NULL, class="butt"),
    tags$head(tags$style(".butt{background-color:#007fad;} .butt{color: white;}")),

    tags$br(),

    #Warning about loading time
    helpText("When you click the button above, it might take a while until the results are ready.",
             "The size of your list directly impacts the waiting time for the query."),

    #Horizontal Line
    tags$hr(),

    #Download Results
    downloadButton('downloadData1', label = "Download Results", class = "btmcolor"),
    tags$head(tags$style(".btmcolor{background-color:#007fad;} .btmcolor{color: white;}"))

  ),

  mainPanel(

    dataTableOutput("result"),
    tags$style(type="text/css", '#result tfoot {display:none;}')
  )

)

#--------------------------------------
# Server
#--------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output) {

  d<-reactiveValues()

  output$preview <- renderTable({

    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.

    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = FALSE, sep =",")

    #This will be printed on the preview
    head(df)

  })

  observeEvent(input$startQuery,{


    output$result <- renderDataTable({

      # Fix data input to format yyyymmdd
      tmp_str <- paste(as.character(input$dates), collapse = " and ")
      tmp_str <- gsub("-", "", tmp_str)

      # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
      # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
      # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
      # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
      # be found.

      inFile <- input$file1

      if (is.null(inFile))
        return(NULL)

      df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = FALSE, sep =",")

      #Prepare file for query

      #read the user file as a single string into csvString
      csvString <- paste(readLines(inFile$datapath), collapse=", ")
      print(csvString)

      #put all emails into 1 string with quotes around each
      csvString <- paste0(sprintf("%s", csvString), collapse = ", ")

      #Authenticate on DB
      ds <- "authentication string. custom library"

      #Run Query 
      query <- paste0("
                      SELECT item_id, country, total_new_images
                      FROM inventory
                      WHERE item_id IN (", csvString, ")
                      GROUP BY item_id, country
                      ORDER BY item_id
                      ")


      d$data <- ds$execute_query(query) #custom function
      d$result1 <- as.data.frame(d$data)

    })
  })


  #------------------------------------------
  # Download Output
  #------------------------------------------

  observeEvent(input$downloadData1,{

    output$downloadData1 <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        tmp<- paste(as.character(input$dates), collapse = "_")
        tmp <- gsub("-", "", tmp)
        paste0("content_upload_",tmp,".csv") },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(d$result1, file)
      })

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was really a great tip from your side. Now I just need to somehow fetch the results for download. It worked before but now it seems to not function properly

Comment: Oh Sorry, what's the issue now? there's no data downloaded? is there any test csv?